# How can I make my image carousel responsive to display 1 image on mobile size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Currently the Carousel shows 3 images, which is great until mobile which I would like to display a single image which can be navigated through, can anybody edit my code or push me in the right direction to discover how it can be achieved 
Here is the html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid imageCarousel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="container carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
                 <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
                        <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="img/home-image1.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="img/home-image2.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="img/home-image3.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="img/home-image4.png" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/carousel-inner-->
                </div><!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the current JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})
$('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

});

Comment: If you want to do more advanced things with carousels, I advise you drop the Bootstrap built in one and look at Owl Carousel.

Comment: I'll take a look now, thank you DavidG

Comment: Owl or slick are two of carousels that will do it for you: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ Both are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `col` values for all window sizes. An example would be `col-sm-12 col-xs-12` for small windowed devices and `col-md-12 col-lg-12` for larger windowed devices

Comment: I gave that a go but no luck, I think its the built in Bootstrap Carousel that is difficult to ammend